# BeforeStep AfterStep aren't called

Tags: cucumber, hook

I created a hook and is using @Before, @After , @BeforeStep, @AfterStep.
1.
The pom I set is as below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with this setting,Only @Before, @After work.@BeforeStep, @AfterStep don't work. How to fix it.

If I change the version of cucumber-java to latest version 6.9.1  But the following are invalid,

```
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;
import cucumber.api.java.BeforeStep;
```

which package should I import?

Is anyone able to help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with package-
io.cucumber.java